# I'm using a version of pmdarima that no longer includes statsmodels ARIMA or ARMA class. How do I interpret SARIMAX without pdq?

Tags: pmdarima, sarimax

auto_arima(df1['Births'],seasonal=False).summary()

SARIMAX Results
Dep. Variable:  y   No. Observations:   120
Model:  SARIMAX Log Likelihood  -409.745
Date:   Mon, 23 Aug 2021    AIC 823.489
Time:   06:55:06    BIC 829.064
Sample: 0   HQIC    825.753

- 120
  Covariance Type:    opg
  coef    std err z   P>|z|   [0.025  0.975]
  intercept   39.7833 0.687   57.896  0.000   38.437  41.130
  sigma2  54.1197 8.319   6.506   0.000   37.815  70.424
  Ljung-Box (L1) (Q): 0.85    Jarque-Bera (JB):   2.69
  Prob(Q):    0.36    Prob(JB):   0.26
  Heteroskedasticity (H): 0.80    Skew:   0.26
  Prob(H) (two-sided):    0.48    Kurtosis:   2.48

Warnings:
[1] Covariance matrix calculated using the outer product of gradients (complex-step).
auto_arima(df1['Births'],seasonal=False)
auto_arima(df1['Births'],seasonal=False)